# plpgsql: Cast 'new' record for insert statement

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I try to build a history inside a table. Part of the history function are the following table attributes:

```
id: uuid
historycounter: int8
```

Each time a dataset is added to the table its `historycounter` is set to zero.
Each time a dataset is update the `historycounter` should be increased by one.
A `before insert or update or delete on <table> for each row` should do all the work.

For the update part of the trigger function this looks as follows:

```
execute format('update %I.%I set historycounter = historycounter + 1 where id = $1', schema_name, tab_name) using old.id;
--  execute format('insert into %I.%I select $1', schema_name, tab_name) using new::text:xx;
execute format('insert into %I.%I values ($1)', schema_name, tab_name) using new.*::text;
return null;
```

Updating the historycounter works fine. But what ever I try, I did not find a way to do the conversion from UPDATE into INSERT. I like to build it on the most generic way possible. So knowing and adding each attribute of the dataset (table) is not a way.

As far as I know `new` and `old` are of the type `record`. Casting a record to `row` should do the trick, but HOW?

Any hints are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unpack composite value inside `INSERT` statement. This is SQL feature (not plpgsql feature). So using star `*` in `USING` clause should not to work. `NEW` and `OLD` are not record variables. They are composite variables with known type.

```
create table foo(a int, b varchar, c int);
create table foo2( a int, b varchar, c int);

create or replace function foo_insert_trg()
returns trigger as $$
begin
  execute 'insert into foo2 values($1.*)' using new;
  return null;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

insert into foo values(10, 'ahoj', 20);
INSERT 0 0
select * from foo2;
┌────┬──────┬────┐
│ a  │  b   │ c  │
╞════╪══════╪════╡
│ 10 │ ahoj │ 20 │
└────┴──────┴────┘
(1 row)
```